# Application stuck at "Powered by Titanium screen"

Tags: titanium

I'm trying to run an app made on Titanium in my cellphone. At first it was working fine, until i decided to debug my code. After that whenever i try to run it on my cellphone, it gets stuck @ the powered by titanium screen (that red one).

I tried to delete my build folder as some people said after a bit o research but it won't work.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Did you checked error log? If nothing is there, check if you call `.open()` method on your main view.

Comment: Does it happens only when you connect with your machine? Are you using any breakpoints? Please be more specific, show some code or more description.

Answer (score 1):

What I would try to do is:

- clean the project (it also deletes the build folder, but I think it also cleans some more stuff in there).
- when the app starts try to set an alert in app.js as the first thing - see if this alert shows, and if it does - move it to the next step until you find a place where it is no longer shown which might indicate that this is where you problem is.
- Look at the device logs - if it's an android device open ddms and look at the logs while you run the app - see if anything pops up. If it's an iPhone on xCode you have some sort of console viewer for the phone (sorry - can't remember the name right now).
- make sure you are not still running under debug mode.

BTW - you didn't mention if it happens on iPhone or Android? does it happens on the simulator as well?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  From digging through Appcelerator's Jira I found we weren't alone, and also got a workaround that allows us to get past the splash screen.  Check to see if there is a `deploy.json` file located in your application's directory on the device.  If so **delete** it!

Here is more info on the issue https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16086.
It's rated as a high priority to be corrected for the 3.3.0 SDK release.